# How to implement a process that uses flutter_secure_storage package to read and write the data [with Provider package]

Tags: flutter, provider

I'm  new to Flutter and Dart. I made a simple Todos app with Provider package and Consumer. I'm trying to implement a process that uses flutter_secure_storage package to read and write the list data on the device.
But I don't know how to implement it.

Checkbox widget requires a bool, while secure_storage requires the type of String. Therefore, it is necessary to convert both types. This also confuses me a little.

The code is below.
I would be happy if you could give me some advice.

**main.dart**

```
// Todos app example

import 'package:consumer_samp/list_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider<ListModel>(
        create: (context) => ListModel(),
        child: MyHomePage('Todos app example'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage(this.title);

  final String title;

  final TextEditingController eCtrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Enter your ToDo item',
                      ),
                      controller: eCtrl,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Consumer<ListModel>(
                    builder: (_, listModel, __) => FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Add'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (eCtrl.text != '') {
                          Map<String, dynamic> item = {
                            'value': false,
                            'text': eCtrl.text
                          };
                          listModel.addItem(item);
                          eCtrl.clear();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Consumer<ListModel>(builder: (_, listModel, __) {
                var items = listModel.getItems;
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 300,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: items.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int idx) =>
                            Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Checkbox(
                                  value: items[idx]['value'],
                                  onChanged: (val) {
                                    listModel.toggleValue(idx, val);
                                  }),
                              Text(
                                items[idx]['text'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 21, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**list_model.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class ListModel with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _items = [];

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> get getItems => _items;

  void addItem(Map<String, dynamic> item) {
    _items.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleValue(int idx, bool val) {
    _items[idx]['value'] = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use class `TodoItem` and save/load with JSON String 
`Provider` logic for secure storage is in full code, too long to describe detail
code snippet

```
List<TodoItem> todoItemFromJson(String str) =>
    List<TodoItem>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => TodoItem.fromJson(x)));

String todoItemToJson(List<TodoItem> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class TodoItem {
  TodoItem({
    this.item,
    this.checked,
  });

  String item;
  bool checked;

  factory TodoItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TodoItem(
        item: json["item"],
        checked: json["checked"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "item": item,
        "checked": checked,
      };
}
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

import 'dart:convert';

List<TodoItem> todoItemFromJson(String str) =>
    List<TodoItem>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => TodoItem.fromJson(x)));

String todoItemToJson(List<TodoItem> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class TodoItem {
  TodoItem({
    this.item,
    this.checked,
  });

  String item;
  bool checked;

  factory TodoItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TodoItem(
        item: json["item"],
        checked: json["checked"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "item": item,
        "checked": checked,
      };
}

class ListModel with ChangeNotifier {
  FlutterSecureStorage _storage;

  List<TodoItem> _items = [];

  List<TodoItem> get getItems => _items;

  initilaize() async {
    print("initialize");
    String jsonString = await _storage.read(key: "todo");
    if (jsonString != null) {
      _items = todoItemFromJson(jsonString);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  ListModel.init(FlutterSecureStorage storage) {
    print("init");
    _storage = storage;
    initilaize();
  }

  void update(FlutterSecureStorage storage) {
    print("update");
    _storage = storage;
  }

  void addItem(TodoItem item) {
    _items.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleValue(int idx, bool val) {
    _items[idx].checked = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          Provider<FlutterSecureStorage>(create: (_) => FlutterSecureStorage()),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<FlutterSecureStorage, ListModel>(
            create: (_) {
              return ListModel.init(
                  Provider.of<FlutterSecureStorage>(_, listen: false));
            },
            update: (_, storage, listModel) => listModel..update(storage),
          ),
        ],
        child: MyHomePage('Todos app example'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage(this.title);

  final String title;

  final TextEditingController eCtrl = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Consumer2<ListModel, FlutterSecureStorage>(
              builder: (_, listModel, storage, __) => IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.save),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await storage.write(
                          key: "todo", value: todoItemToJson(listModel._items));
                      print("save done");
                    },
                  ))
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Enter your ToDo item',
                      ),
                      controller: eCtrl,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Consumer<ListModel>(
                    builder: (_, listModel, __) => FlatButton(
                      child: Text('Add'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (eCtrl.text != '') {
                          Map<String, dynamic> item = {
                            'value': false,
                            'text': eCtrl.text
                          };
                          listModel.addItem(
                              TodoItem(item: eCtrl.text, checked: false));
                          eCtrl.clear();
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Consumer<ListModel>(builder: (_, listModel, __) {
                var items = listModel.getItems;
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 300,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: items.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int idx) =>
                            Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          color: Colors.green,
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Checkbox(
                                  value: items[idx].checked,
                                  onChanged: (val) {
                                    listModel.toggleValue(idx, val);
                                  }),
                              Text(
                                items[idx].item,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 21, color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you chunhunghan, I'll try it later.

Comment: Your code completely worked as expected! I understood it roughly. I'll try to understand deeply about ChangeNotifierProxyProvider, Consumer2 and so on. And I'm going to challenge to implement auto save when the Add button or Checkbox is pressed. Thank you for your excellent code.

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the readme files by the following link

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

The following code instantiate the storage, and the following code's must be in a `async` method as this returns a future.

```
final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
```

And you can pass the `_items` list as a value and you can set some key name

```
await storage.write(key: key, value: _items);
```

And then you could get that value by using the key name (which is set while storing)

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> _value = await storage.read(key: key);
```

And then you could map the `_value` you get from storage and you can store it in `_items`. And then you could do various operations and queries inside your app now with all data you have.

Make a note! I haven't tried this approach in my code base. Just I said what I thought. Please try this in your code and comment me please.

The following code executes correctly use this in model, for storing data:

```
Future<void> _storingData() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; i++) {
        await storage
              .write(key: _items[i]['text'], value: "${_items[i]['value']}")
              .then((value) => print("success"));
    }
}
```

For retrieving data:

```
Future<void> retrivingData() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    Map<String, String> allValues = await storage.readAll();

    print(allValues);

    allValues.forEach((key, value) {
        bool val = bool.fromEnvironment(value, defaultValue: false);
        Map<String, dynamic> item = {'value': val, 'text': key};
        addItem(item);
    });
}
```

and finally I stored all values again to a list.

You should do some changes in your code in `main.dart` according to the above methods based on your usage.

Comment: I thinks so the type of the value we pass while storing may cause errors, which you check it and say me please

Comment: Thank you Abilash, I'll try it later.

Comment: Thank you Abilash. Your advise helped me to understand and implement chunhunghan's code.

Comment: Most welcome cogane64 . If its useful please give a like to this answer.